# Refresh a checklist box in windows form

Tags: c#, .net, list, windows-forms-designer

I am trying to browse files from a location and want to show it in a windows form checklistbox. It should work both adding and removing files from directory. I have tried with a tricker

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PopulateListBoxIsRefresh(chklistscripts, Helper.ScriptPath, "*.sql");
    chklistscripts.Refresh();
}

private void PopulateListBoxIsRefresh(ListBox lsb, string Folder, string FileType)
{
    DirectoryInfo dinfo = new DirectoryInfo(Folder);
    FileInfo[] files = dinfo.GetFiles(FileType);

    foreach (FileInfo file in files.OrderByDescending(p => p.CreationTime))
    {
        if (!File.Exists(file.FullName))
        {
            lsb.Items.Add(file.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

what is the easiest tweak to resolve it.

I want below scenarios.

No file
File add
File Remove

Comment: "I have tried with a tricker" <= what makes you think using a politician will help you?

Comment: Why are you passing the ListBox to the method? This method should be on the form, and the ListBox will be accessible without passing it in. If you step through that method, is the foreach block entered (are files found)?

Comment: If the file does not exist, add the file to the list?  You might want to consider a [FileSystemWatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx) class, btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `FileSystemWatcher` like this:

```
FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
watcher.Path = Folder;
watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite | 
               NotifyFilters.DirectoryName | NotifyFilters.FileName;
watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnCreated);
watcher.Deleted += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
watcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(OnRenamed);
watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
```

For details please see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx

It is better to use an async event handler rather than waste CPU cycles on polling.

Comment: Exactly did the same.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

i think the problem is your if statement condition,change it like this:

```
if (File.Exists(file.FullName))
    {
        lsb.Items.Add(file.Name);
    }
```